# How to get data.frame in Java using Rserve

Tags: java, r, rserve

I use [Twitter anomaly detection algorithm](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection) in my project. For this purpose I use **Rserve** library to run *R* code in my *Java* application.

My Java code:

```
RConnection connection = new RConnection();
connection.voidEval("library(AnomalyDetection)");
connection.eval("res <- AnomalyDetectionTs(data.frame(/*list of timestamps*/,/*list of values*/), direction='both', plot=FALSE, longterm=TRUE)");
```

And, as a result, I got this output:

```
    $anoms
              timestamp    anoms
1   1980-09-25 16:05:00  21.3510
2   1980-09-29 06:40:00 193.1036
3   1980-09-29 21:44:00 148.1740
```

To get results now I'm using this **not nice** solution:
`connection.eval("write.csv(res[['anoms']],file='anom.csv')");`

Then I open this file in Java and parse the results.

So, how to get the output results in Java using Rserve possibilities for data.frame structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply write the R command such that it returns the desired result back to Java:

```
RList l = c.eval("AnomalyDetectionTs(data, direction='both',
                 plot=FALSE, longterm=TRUE)$anoms").asList();
```

What you get is the data frame (as a list) with the two variables `timestamp` and `anoms`.

However, `AnomalyDetectionTs` returns dates in a horribly annoying and inefficient format so you may want to actually return a more sane result which is easier to work with in Java, e.g.:

```
RList l = c.eval("{ res <- AnomalyDetectionTs(data, direction='both', plot=FALSE,
                          longterm=TRUE)$anoms;
                  list(as.POSIXct(res$timestamp), res$anoms) }").asList();
double ts[] = l.at(0).asDoubles();
double anom[] = l.at(1).asDoubles();
for (int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++)
    System.out.println(new java.util.Date((long)(ts[i]*1000.0)) + ": " + anom[i]);
```

PS: the right place for Rserve questions is the [stats-rosuda-devel mailing list](https://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) which will give you answers much faster.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you

Comment: This works like a charm, but is there a reason we are not using RVector in place of RList?